# Adding interfaces to non-interfaced derived objects

Tags: delphi, inheritance, interface

I have the following problem that I can't quite wrap my head around. Suppose I have some classes:

```
TClassA = class 
TClassB = class( TClassA ) 

IMyList = interface( IXList<TClassB> )
TMyList = class( TXList<TClassB>, IMyList )

TMyThing1 = class( TClassB )
TListOfMyThing1 = class( TMyList )

TMyThing2 = class( TClassB )
TListOfMyThing2 = class( TMyList )

TListOfMyThingLists = class( TXList<TMyList> )
```

Basically, I've got a base object (TClassB) and several classes derived from it. I also have a base list object (TMyList) that contains these objects.

Each of the derived objects has a container for them derived from the base container.

Finally, I've got a list-of-lists where I add each of the lists.

The idea is to be able to iterate through the list-of-lists, then iterate through each list and apply methods common to all of them: parse, validate, render, etc.

It compiles fine and runs ... until it shuts down, when I get a few GPFs, and the memory dump shows a ton of memory leaks. I guess this is a side-effect of using interfaces at one inheritance level but not beyond that (ie., IMyList/TMyList).

Where I'm stumped is how to add interfaces to the latter two sets of classes. TClassB is derived from TObject and has no interface in it.  What I *think* I need (at least, what's OBVIOUS) is something like this:

```
IMyThing1 = interface( TClassB, IInterface )
TMyThing1 = class( TClassB, TInterfacedObject, IMyThing1 )
```

But this is not legal! (It's multiple inheritance. BAD!)

If I just use what's legal to derive from TClassB:

```
IMyThing1 = interface( TClassB, IInterface )
TMyThing1 = class( TClassB, IMyThing1 )
```

the compiler (DXE5) complains:

```
[dcc32 Error] x.pas(#): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IInterface.QueryInterface
[dcc32 Error] x.pas(#): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IInterface._AddRef
[dcc32 Error] x.pas(#): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IInterface._Release
```

although the line# is off in the weeds somewhere. (IOW, it doesn't actually tell me where the error is. I can only determine that by selectively commenting out code.)

Is it necessary to explicitly implement these interface functions for every class derived from a non-interfaced class in order to keep "managed" objects from being "mis-managed"?

Or perhaps there's another approach that's not as obvious?

(This seems to be a problem mainly because the folks at Borland-Inprise-CG-EMBT have fundamental religious objections to implementing "real" multiple inheritance simply because stupid people can do stupid things with it...)

As an aside, this is a *LOT* of fricking work just to get automatic reference counting (ARC) added to classes!

NOTE: this may have been answered earlier, but I have no idea how to phrase the question to get it to show up in a search.

Comment: When you say _TClassB is derived from TObject_ do you really mean it is derived from _TClassA and this one derives from TObject_? Anyway, I surely am missing something but, why do you not derive the base class from `TInterfacedObject`?

Comment: Yes, TClassB is derived from TObject through TClassA. I didn't write TClassA. But I'm looking around for a compatible object that's derived from it that DOES implement the IInterface methods.

Comment: I guess there's problems with your code, but we cannot see nearly enough of it to know what those problems are.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is going on because there is not enough to tell but you can look at the [implements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_Implements_for_Delegation) as that might help you. For Delphi XE3 and later you can delegate to a child object that is reference counted.

Comment: Sorry, it's just way too long to paste in all of the code, mainly because it's all the same scaffolding. This code should be easily generated with a macro or something. The amount of redundancy is ridiculous.

Comment: Either you want help or not.

Comment: There's no information in the scaffolding. It's the inheritance hierarchy I'm having trouble with.

Comment: There certainly is information there. And in the code that uses these classes. That explains the leaks.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good idea to mix interfaced and non-interfaced object pointers, especially if you retrieve interfaces from non-interfaced object pointers.  If you use interfaces, you should use interfaces for everything, including variables and inside containers.  That being said, to make this code work without crashing, you will likely have to override `_AddRef()` and `_Release()` to disable reference counting on your classes that implement interfaces.  `TComponent` does this, for instance.

Comment: Once you add an interface to a class hierarchy, I guess you're doomed to ensure everything from that point on has both a class and interface defined for it, eh?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's the very basics of inheritance. When you inherit, you inherit everything.

Comment: @Remy What do you mean by "non-interfaced object pointers"? I don't quite understand the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to implement the missing methods yourself so that the compiler is satisfied. There's a great article with more details here: https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/delphi-interfaces-without-reference-counting/

Or, perhaps better yet, just inherit from TSingletonImplementation -- it implements the required methods for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a class derived from TClassA that's a TInterfacedClassA that I derived TClassB from instead.

```
TInterfacedClassA = class
TClassB = class( TInterfacedClassA )
```

For the rest, I did this:

```
IMyList = interface( IXList<TClassB> )
TMyList = class( TXList<TClassB>, IMyList )

IMyThing1 = interface( IInterface )
TMyThing1 = class( TClassB, IInterface )
IListOfMyThing1 = interface( IInterface )
TListOfMyThing1 = class( TMyList, IListOfMyThing1 )

IMyThing2 = interface( IInterface )
TMyThing2 = class( TClassB, IInterface )
IListOfMyThing2 = interface( IInterface )
TListOfMyThing2 = class( TMyList, IListOfMyThing2 )

TListOfMyThingLists = class( TXList<TMyList> )
```

All of the setters and getters in the classes were changed to use the Ixxx types rather than Txxx types where they're used, and the methods were also changed to pass and return Ixxx types instead of Txxx types.

This works, except to Add things the list, I need to do it this way:

```
TListOfMyThing1.Add( aItem : IMyThing1 ) : integer;
begin
    Result := inherited Add( aItem as TClassB );
end;
```

This seems odd to me because aItem is actually derived from TClassB.

Maybe I need an IClassB to derive the other interfaces from instead of IInterface?

Comment: I get a down-vote for sharing what I did? That's rich.  There are plenty of questions here where people say they solved the problem, but never say what or how. I guess they're just avoiding downvotes from people who think it's inappropriate to provide such information.